# React Native useNavigation class Component

Tags: react-native

I am using a class component and I want to navigate from here to another screen. But it says navigate is undefined. I look up to the docs and I realised I need to use `userNavigation`[This](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/). but i don't how to actually use it. Someone helps please

```
export default class ReduxScreen extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View>
           <Button block style={{ marginHorizontal: 30, marginTop: 50 }} onPress={() => {
         //I want to add the useNavigation here

            }}>
             <Text style={{ color: '#FFF' }}>Start</Text>
          </Button>
        </View>
    )
}}
```

Answer (score 5):

`useNavigation` is a hook and hooks can only be used inside a functional component like this.

```
 const navigation = useNavigation()
```

But as you are using the class component so you can navigate like this.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('YouScreen', {paramsIfAny})
```

`But you have to make sure that navigation prop is available` in your class component by putting `console.log` if it's available then the above line will work if not then you have to follow this.

Note: `navigation prop is always available in the parent route(Route which is used to navigate some screen)`

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop

Another solution is you can pass navigation prop from your functional component to a class component like this.

```
export default function RootFunction (){
const navigation = useNavigation() // extract navigation prop here 

 return <ReduxScreen navigation={navigation} /> //pass to your component.

  }




class ReduxScreen extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button block style={{ marginHorizontal: 30, marginTop: 50}}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('YourScreen')
                  // now prop will be available here
          }}>
          <Text style={{ color: '#FFF' }}>Start</Text>
        </Button>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who are struggling with route v6 and more.
You must define a function outside of your component Class and use it as following:

```
function myParams(Component) {
    return props => <Component navHook={useNavigate()} />;
}
```

in your Class component:

```
this.props.navHook('/SomeWhere')
```

And keep in mind you have wrap your Class in your function:

```
export default myParams(Card);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those struggling with TypeScript and @vahid-sabet 's proposal:

```js
export type NavComponentProps<T extends Readonly<unknown>> =
  T & { navigate: NavigateFunction; };

export class NavComponent<T extends Readonly<unknown>>
  extends React.PureComponent<NavComponentProps<T>> { };

export function navHOC<T extends Readonly<unknown>>
  (Component: typeof NavComponent<T>) {
  return (props: T) => <Component {...props} navigate={useNavigate()} />;
}
```

Then declare your class:

```js
class _MyClass extends NavComponent<MyProps> {
  constructor(props: NavComponentProps<MyProps>) {
    super(props);
    // I can call:
    this.props.navigate();
  }
};
export const MyClass = navHOC(_MyClass);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `<Link />` instead like blow

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';



export default class ReduxScreen extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View>
           <Button component={Link} to="some-where" block style={{ marginHorizontal: 30, marginTop: 50 }} 
            }}>
             <Text style={{ color: '#FFF' }}>Start</Text>
          </Button>
        </View>
    )
}}
```

Answer (score -3):

As seen in the linked docs, you will have to use `functional` component in order to use the navigation hook.

Try this

```js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        block
        style={{ marginHorizontal: 30, marginTop: 50 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('YourScreenHere')}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: '#FFF' }}>Start</Text>
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Hope this helps!