# React js Routing issue with class based component in react 18 with react router 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
const {history} = this.props;
history.push('/admin/user/create');
```

The above code is working in React 17 with React Router 5 but in React 18 with react Router 6 it is not working...

Can anyone help me out? I am using class-based components.

Comment: Does your app build? Do you get an error?

Comment: Since react router v6 history changed to navigation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63921034/8100188

Comment: RRDv6 introduced many changes. I'd recommend you start with the [Getting Started](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview) and [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) guides to catch up.

Answer (score -1):

Since react router v6 history changed to navigate :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63921034/8100188

I don't use class components but i found this for class components :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61612431

From the Docs: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate

I've made a little research and what i found out is that in react router v6 they expect you to wrap your class components in a functional components where you can pass hooks as props as much as you'd like .

If you need more information: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8146

Comment: this.props.navigation.navigate('/admin/user/create') not working becase navigation is not a hook in react router (in react js)

Comment: @PravinJaiswal I've edited my answer i hope it's helpful for you .